# How to put set of animations on 2 buttons through xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, animation, button

I'm playing with animating my buttons, and when I click a button that button is supposed to move along the y-axis and fade out while another button will fade in on the y-axis. I've achieved this by writing the code in my java class and it works perfectly fine, but I want to shift all that code to my XML and call from there. these animations. How can I make a set of animations this way i.e Translate, fade out and another translate and fade in?

```
 public static void crossfade(Button buttonToFadeOut, Button buttonToFadeIn) {

    buttonToFadeIn.setAlpha(0f);
    buttonToFadeIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    buttonToFadeIn.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .translationY(100)  //220
            .setDuration(700)
            .setStartDelay(60)
            .setListener(null);

    buttonToFadeOut.animate()
            .alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(700)
            .translationY(-100)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    buttonToFadeOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Hello. Was my answer able to help you?

Comment: @Ishaan .. Yes sorry i had to go out, replied late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do a fade out in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha
        android:duration="1700"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

You have to create a new Android resource directory in `res` called `anim` and make the above file in the `anim` folder.

Now, to call that animation in Java you would have to do:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fadeout);
```

Now, to apply this animation on your button you would do:

```
button.startAnimation(anim);
```

There is a very useful video on this at the [link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfa6wUfSmrc) that explains how to make the XML files for a variety of animations. I hope that this answer was useful.

Comment: Yes thats perfect. Thankyou so much

Comment: But is there a way to make a set of animations on 2 buttons in one xml file . For example in your xml file you are just fading out , but i want to know if you can fade out a button and translate and then fade in another button and translate , all this code is written in a single xml file ?

Comment: You will be able to gave the fading out and translate for the first button. But you will need a separate file when doing the fade in and translate of the s cond button because each animation has to be set to a certain view. By putting them all into one XML file, then the first button will do all 4 actions. So you'll have to make two separate XML files. If you look at the link I gave you, you should be able to do it. It also has a lot of other animations like translating, zooming in and others.

Comment: Got it. Thankyou